# AsyncTaskLoader vs AsyncTask for loading single entity in Edit single entity activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, asynctaskloader

I am studying Android. I am creating an Activity for editing single entity that loaded from local SQLite. For List of entities activity, I used AsyncTaskLoader to load list of entities. For Editing single entity activity, I don't know I should use AsyncTaskLoader OR AsyncTask to load single entity. Anyone has experience in this, please give me some advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend going with the Loader as it will be tied to the Activity lifecycle and you won't have to worry about updating something on a dead Activity.